# What is the internal & external evidence for the authorship/inclusion of 1 Corinthians 14:34-35 and what evidence is against its inclusion?

Tags: history, textual-criticism, pauline-epistles, historical-criticism

We read:

> “Let your women keep silent in the churches, for they are not
> permitted to speak; but they are to be submissive, as the law also
> says. And if they want to learn something, let them ask their own
> husbands at home; for it is shameful for women to speak in church.”
> ‭‭**I Corinthians‬ ‭14:34-35‬**

**Q: What is the internal & external evidence for the authorship/inclusion of 1 Corinthians 14:34-35 and what evidence is against its inclusion?**

I heard this may be a Scribal Gloss, so PLEASE “bore” me with as much textual criticism info as you can on these verses.  (**T.C. Is one of my favorite subjects, so the more details, the better!**)